# SQL statement failing to execute in Python CGI

Tags: python, sql, cgi

I have an update statement in my database that is not executing. As far as I am aware, it is syntactically correct. I used [this app](https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/) to verify the syntax. The `except` block is all that is being executed and I do not understand why.

Here is the code:

```
for res_posts in list_of_response_ids:
temp_str = res_posts[0] # first element of res_posts tuple is string
temp_str += ":" + str(output[0])
try:
    sql = "UPDATE POST SET res_post_id = %s WHERE post_id = %d;" % (str(temp_str), int(res_posts[1]))
    cursor.execute(sql)
except:
    print "uh oh"
```

I can post more code if this is not enough information.

EDIT: Following Jacob's advice, I used `raise` and got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "post.cgi", line 93, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 173, in     execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':37 WHERE post_id = 8' at line 1")
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Printing a generic message in an except block requires throwing away the Exception details provided by python. I recommend adding `raise` on the line after your print statement so you can see the full stack trace. If you need help interpreting the meaning of this trace, paste it in here.

Comment: I've added the output to my post. Any idea what's wrong with the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your traceback, there is something wrong with the type of entry you are using for the `res_post_id` or `post_id`. Currently you are not passing a representation of the `res_post_id` string, but a literal string. If res_post_id is a string in your DB Schema, I would recommend using %r like so:

```
sql = "UPDATE POST SET res_post_id = %r WHERE post_id = %d;" % (str(temp_str), int(res_posts[1]))
```

This will properly quote your `res_post_id` value for insertion.

So your statement should change from this:

```
UPDATE POST SET res_post_id = :37 WHERE post_id = 8;
```

...to this:

```
UPDATE POST SET res_post_id = ':37' WHERE post_id = 8;
```

Comment: Wow! Didn't realize it had to be so specific! That fixed it, thank you so much!